# I'm getting a atrribute error for this particular program

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Parser(object):

    def __init__(self,tokens):
       self.tokens = tokens
       self.token_index = 0

    def parse(self):

       while self.token_index < len(self.tokens):
           token_type = self.tokens[self.token_index][0]
           token_value = self.tokens[self.token_index][1]
           print(token_type,token_value)
           self.token_index += 1
```

This is the parser file

This is the main file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52BRQ.png)

This is the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kdIn.png)

I have give the screenshots as I was facing error while postng my question so sorry for that
Any rectification will be very helpful

Comment: `parser` is a built-in module. Change the name of your file from `parser.py` to something like `myparser.py`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help....